# How to toggle hidden elements that match the search result source using jQuery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, toggle

How can you toggle or show a hidden element thats in the HTML instead of a database using jQuery Autocomplete?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cazepeda/kMcFZ/21/) that has the elements I've been using. Everything is working fine except I don't know how to proceed in showing the hidden elements that'd match the search sources.

The source variables in the JavaScript match the class names of the hidden elements in the HTML page that has the autocomplete search field. So depending on what element you're searching for (this example searching for HTML5 elements) a result will appear when the source matches the hidden class element.

I've been looking at the [result handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result) but can't seem to wrap my head around it with the code I have now.

Any help regarding my issue would be greatly appreciated. Or if this is to excessive of a use of autocomplete please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work

try jQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ and look at the events section.

for example if the user where to search for a "sport" and you wanted a div with sports news to appear

you could write a custom search option like this EG:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   search: function(event, ui) { 
      if($( ".selector" ).val() == "sport"){
         // open sport div
         $("#sport").fadeIn();
      }
  }
});
```

is this what you meant?

let me know how you go and if i can help any further

Comment: This sounds like what I'm trying to achieve. I'm going to give this a go right now and see. I'll update asap. I'm working this here: http://jsfiddle.net/cazepeda/kMcFZ/21/

Comment: I'm unfortunately still struggling with what I'm trying to achieve. Tomorrow I'll give it another go.